# spring web application initialization from database on startup

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Spring 3.1 + Tomcat

I have a bit of a design question here:

There are a group of categories that have been specified in a database. These categories can be considered global in the sense that they could be used throughout the webapp. What I would like to do is read these categories on server startup and populate some type of collection in Java. The only need to be read from the database once at startup, consider it a type of initialization.

Two options I can think of:

1) Should I use a NON lazily initialized bean?

or

2) Modifying the web.xml?

I'm not really sure what is the preferred method, and any instructions on how to perform your recommended would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options you have provided are most commonly used:

1. Use singleton non-lazy bean with a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` (but be aware that `@Transactional` [might not work](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58337)). You can have several beans with such initialization routine.
2. Extend `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` and use it in `web.xml`. I find this solution less elegant and also promoting bad programming style (extending with call to `super` to enhance the base class)

Comment: I went with Method 1, but instead of using PostContrust, I used the init-method attribute in the bean definition, seems to be what I needed.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the same. In fact `init-method` is least invasive (you can also implement `InitializingBean`) because it leaves absolutely no dependencies on your bean.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a `Controller` that implements both `ServletContextAware` and `InitializingBean`.  The controller runs at app startup and I run my parameter loading code in the `afterPropertiesSet` method so that the ServletContext is correctly injected.  Then the properties are available throughout the application from the ServletContext.  Code:

```
@Controller
public class ParameterizationController implements ServletContextAware , InitializingBean  {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
public static final String PARAMETERS_SC_ATTRIBUTE = "allProps";

private ServletContext sc;

public ParameterizationController() {
    logger.info("inside ParameterizationController...");
}

@Autowired
private SomeService someService;

@RequestMapping("/loadparams.do")
public String formHandler(
        Model model) {
    String forwardValue = "/loadparams";
    // an admin can also call this page to reload props at runtime
    this.sc.setAttribute(PARAMETERS_SC_ATTRIBUTE, loadProperties());
    return forwardValue;
}

private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> loadProperties() {
    return someService.loadProperties();
}

// makes sure the SC is injected for use
public void setServletContext(ServletContext sc) {
    this.sc = sc;
}

// only runs after all injections have been completed
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    this.sc.setAttribute(PARAMETERS_SC_ATTRIBUTE, loadProperties());
}
```