# Spring Web Application: doing something on startup (initialization)

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, initialization, startup

I want to fill some tables of my DB from a text file on startup, I want my initialization method to be called only when my application do start.

I am using Spring (+MVC) and Hibernate with MySQL.

how can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [spring web application initialization from database on startup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082594/spring-web-application-initialization-from-database-on-startup)

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: is is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082594/spring-web-application-initialization-from-database-on-startup, because the information flow is the other way arround, so one could use other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: It's very similar. Mine is a little more generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute method on startup in spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401489/execute-method-on-startup-in-spring)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the postconstuct annotation somewhere inside a bean :

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
     //startup logic here
}
```

Probably makes (desgin) sense to use a configuration bean, but it can be any bean at all.

Comment: Ok so the right way can be making a "Initializator" singleton and @PostConstruct a method? Thank you! :)

Comment: This does not work for starting AsyncTasks.  Use sinuhepop's recommendation below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9680800/1019307

Answer (score 18):

You can create an application listener, it's designed specifically for such needs. In this case it will be executed every time context is started (or refreshed).

```
@Component
public class DatabaseFillerOnStartup implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for to do a self-diagnostic. Thank you!

Comment: But this will be invoked in test cases as well and DB is not available for test cases. How to address such scenario?

Comment: @Pokuri: You have a couple of options. 1) don't declare this bean in `@Configuration` for tests, the same way you probably don't declare `@Controller` or `@Scheduled` tasks. 2) Add some conditional logic in this method, maybe analysing stack trace in order to know if you are in a jUnit test. Obviously, first is preferred.

Answer (score 7):

Hibernate comes with an way to add some files with sql statements that will be executed on startup.

The parameter is `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files`.

@See [Hibernate Reference: Chapter 3.4. Optional configuration properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional)

- Table 3.7. Miscellaneous Properties
- hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files:

> Comma-separated names of the optional files containing SQL DML
>   statements executed during the SessionFactory creation. This is useful
>   for testing or demoing: by adding INSERT statements for example you
>   can populate your database with a minimal set of data when it is
>   deployed.
>
> File order matters, the statements of a give file are executed before
>   the statements of the following files. These statements are only
>   executed if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set
>   to create or create-drop.
>
> e.g. /humans.sql,/dogs.sql

*I fond some hints that this may only work if hibernate is started in 'create' mode. But I am not sure.*

Comment: very useful. It's not the answer to the question itself but.... THAT'S just what I need! THANK YOU! However, I can't make import_files work :( Instead of it I put a "import.sql" in my classpath, it executes perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Two options,

First: Let hibernate create your ddl everytime the services is startup(Only for local or dev environment)

```
<bean id="hibernateVendor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
      p:showSql="false"
      p:generateDdl="true"/>
```

Or create in spring a Bean with init-lazy false and add in there the logic to create the database if you dont have it or inject your script, or do whatever you want.

```
 <bean id="bootstrapStartup" class="com.tscompany.rest.bootstrap.BootstrapStartup" lazy-init="false" init-method="init"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create some bean in root-context configuration - like

```
<bean id="someBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="someProperty">
        ... description of the property
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="methodName" />
</bean>
```

Thus - on application startup method "methodName" will be invoked. We have DB upgrades implemented in such a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property set to `create` or `create-drop` then the easiest way to do that is by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property with SQL file name that contains SQL statements to load your initial data into the database schema, e.g. initial application users.

The following is an example method that I have in my `DatabaseConfig` class. It sets `hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files` property with SQL file name *import_initial_data.sql* that contains SQL Insert statements to load my initial data to the database schema.

```
   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean hibernate5SessionFactoryBean(){
      LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource((DataSource) appContext.getBean("DataSource"));
      localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses( AppUser.class );
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","create-drop");
      properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "import_initial_data.sql");
      properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
      localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(properties);
      return localSessionFactoryBean;
   }
```

This is my `AppUser.java` in `model` package:

```
package com.beniregev.model;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class AppUser {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
   @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String userName;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String password;

   public AppUser(String userName, String password) {
      this.userName = userName;
      this.password = password;
   }
}
```

Maven dependency for *lombok*:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <version>1.16.6</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The *import_initial_data.sql* file that I have in `resources` directory:

```
INSERT INTO appuser(username, password) VALUES ('jesus', 'christ');
INSERT INTO appuser(username, password) VALUES ('mary', 'virgin');
INSERT INTO appuser(username, password) VALUES ('josef', 'who?');
INSERT INTO appuser(username, password) VALUES ('jeremaia', 'profet');
COMMIT;
```

And the result of *SELECT * FROM appuser;*:

[image: Resultset of SELECT * FROM appuser;]